# Python code giving different results on two different systems

Tags: python

I am using a code where I am generating a file in .bts format which is used to describe velocities in a wind field. When I run this code on my laptop up until the generation of the velocities both codes give the same output(variable called 'out' used in code). However when the file is written and I check the wind fields they are totally different. The following code is used to write the file.

```
 with open(path + '.bts', 'wb') as fl:
        # write the header
        fl.write(pack(_TS_BIN_FMT,
                      [7, 8][periodic],  # 7 is not periodic, 8 is periodic
                      nz,
                      ny,
                      0,  # assuming 0 tower points below grid
                      nt,
                      dz,
                      dy,
                      dt,
                      uhub,
                      zhub,
                      z[0],
                      u_scl[0],
                      u_off[0],
                      u_scl[1],
                      u_off[1],
                      u_scl[2],
                      u_off[2],
                      len(desc_str)))
        fl.write(desc_str.encode(encoding='UTF-8'))
        # Swap the y and z indices so that fortran-order writing agrees with the file format.
        # Also, we swap the order of z-axis to agree with the file format.
        # Write the data so that the first index varies fastest (F order).
        # The indexes vary in the following order:
        # component (fastest), y-index, z-index, time (slowest).
        fl.write(np.rollaxis(out, 2, 1).tobytes(order='F'))
```

Has anyone got any clue what the problem might be. I am using the same python version, same modules through virtual environment and this problem has wrecked my brain. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This may depend on _TS_BIN_FMT, the endianness or byte order is by default system-dependent. See the struct module's documentation for more information.

Comment: The operating system installed on both PCs is Windows 10. As far as my laptop chipset is concerned it is Intel while the other device has AMD.

Comment: The endiannes on both systems is little.

Comment: For the value of is_TS_BIN_FMT '<h4l12fl'